# MySqlDataAdapter.update() doesn't update DataRow with DataRelation

Tags: mysql, vb.net, dataset

I have two Table, the first is "Employee" and the second is "YearEmployee".
The foreign key of "YearEmployee" is the Primary Key of "Employee".
I want to add two Datarow with DataRelation in a Dataset, but i'm getting "a foreign key constraint fails".
I know i can write the first datarow in the Database and after that make the Relation between both DataRow, but I would like to update the whole Dataset with only one Function call.
Someone know this problem or can identify what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you for you help and sorry for my bad english..

My Code:

### Retreiving data from Database

```
Public Shared Sub sub_mysql_get_all_dataset(ByVal dsDataset As DataSet, ByVal strTable() As String)
    Dim dbConnection As New MySqlConnection
    Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

    dbConnection.ConnectionString = _strConnStr

    Try
        dbConnection.Open()
        For Each strTable_row As String In strTable
            dbAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & strTable_row, dbConnection)
            dbAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
            dbAdapter.FillSchema(dsDataset, SchemaType.Source, strTable_row)
            dbAdapter.Fill(dsDataset, strTable_row)
        Next
        dbConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

### Updating data in the database and updating the dataset

```
    Public Shared Function func_mysql_update_dataset(ByVal dsDataset As DataSet, ByVal strTable() As String) As Boolean

    Dim dbConnection As New MySqlConnection
    Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

    dbConnection.ConnectionString = _strConnStr

    Try
        dbConnection.Open()

        For Each strTable_row As String In strTable
            dbAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & strTable_row, dbConnection)
            Dim cb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(dbAdapter)

            dbAdapter.Update(dsDataset, strTable_row)
            dbAdapter.Fill(dsDataset, strTable_row)
        Next
        dbConnection.Close()

        func_mysql_update_dataset = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        func_mysql_update_dataset = False
    End Try
End Function
```

### Initialize the Dataset

```
    Public Shared ds_Employee As New DataSet
    Database.sub_mysql_get_all_dataset(ds_Employee, {"Employee", "YearEmployee", "WorkHours"})

    Dim rel_Emp_To_YEmp As DataRelation = ds_Employee.Relations.Add("PK_Employee_to_FK_YearEmployee", ds_Employee.Tables("Employee").Columns("IDEmployee"), ds_Employee.Tables("YearEmployee").Columns("EmployeeID"))
    Dim rel_YEmp_To_WHours As DataRelation = ds_Employee.Relations.Add("PK_YearEmployee_to_FK_WorkHours", ds_Employee.Tables("YearEmployee").Columns("IDYearEmployee"), ds_Employee.Tables("WorkHours").Columns("YearEmployeeID"))
```

### Adding Datarow

```
    Dim dr_Employee As DataRow = ds_Employee.Tables("Employee").NewRow()

    dr_Employee("DepartementID") = WPF_Emp_CbBxDepartement.SelectedItem.Key
    dr_Employee("FirstName") = WPF_Emp_txtBxFName.Text
    ds_Employee.Tables("Employee").Rows.Add(dr_Employee)


    Dim dr_YearEmployee As DataRow = ds_Employee.Tables("YearEmployee").NewRow()
    dr_YearEmployee.SetParentRow(ds_Employee.Tables("Employee").Rows(ds_Employee.Tables("Employee").Rows.Count - 1), ds_Employee.Tables("YearEmployee").ParentRelations("PK_Employee_to_FK_YearEmployee"))
    dr_YearEmployee("fromDate") = CType(tp_YearEmployee.Controls(0).Controls.Find("UC_YE_DTP_From", False).First, DateTimePicker).Value
       ds_Employee.Tables("YearEmployee").Rows.Add(dr_YearEmployee)
```

### Write in the Database

```
Database.func_mysql_update_dataset(ds_Employee, {"Employee", "YearEmployee"})
```

Comment: Does the database generate the primary key for the `Employee` table? If so, are you retrieving that value back into your `DataSet` so that the `YearEmployee` row has the correct foreign key? You normally select the value back into the parent row and have it propagated to the child row by the `DataRelation` via the `UpdateRule` of the `ForeignKeyConstraint`.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney, yes the database generate both primary key, they are integer unique and auto-increment. With dbAdapter.Fill(dsDataset, strTable_row) in the update function I'm retrieving it other? For the ForeignkeyConstraint, i wrote that rel_Emp_To_YEmp.ChildKeyConstraint.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade, but made no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a handler on the RowUpdated.

### The Function Hanlder

```
Private Shared Sub dbAdapter_RowUpdated(sender As Object, e As MySqlRowUpdatedEventArgs)
    If (e.StatementType = StatementType.Insert And e.Status = UpdateStatus.Continue) Then
        Dim identityQuery As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select @@IDENTITY")
        Dim strIDTable As String = "ID" & e.TableMapping.DataSetTable
        identityQuery.Connection = e.Command.Connection

        e.Row(strIDTable) = identityQuery.ExecuteScalar
    End If
End Sub
```

To use it just add the hanlder before the update() method and remove it after update() execute, like that:

```
' ### ADD REFRESH ID HANDLER '
AddHandler dbAdapter.RowUpdated, AddressOf dbAdapter_RowUpdated

' ### WRITE DATASET '
dbAdapter.Update(dsDataset, strTable_row)

' ### DELETE REFRESH ID HANDLER '
RemoveHandler dbAdapter.RowUpdated, AddressOf dbAdapter_RowUpdated
```

Sources:
[1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f1357fc-f01b-4251-9c99-fa3a7d55cea6/retrieve-identity-value-from-inserted-row-in-access-database-using-tableadapter?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)
[2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdated(v=vs.110).aspx)